# What is the text length limit for ISC BIND zone record names and data?

Tags: bind

One of my users wants to have a TXT record for DKIM, which apparently is very long. The system that automates zone file creation has a very small limit on name and data field length; I can easily increase this, but I may as well set it to the maximum that BIND allows; but what is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That question has a complex answer. See it is here:

http://groups.google.com/group/comp.protocols.dns.bind/browse_thread/thread/c7855d97dc62ed7b?pli=1